# Find values in specific column of unknown table in PostgreSQL from information_schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, information-schema

Using pl/pgsql I've hacked together an update function to run on a bunch of tables that I need to change but I don't know all the names of. What I do know is THEY ALL have a primary key (which could be named anything) and a column specifically called 'metadata'. For example of one of these 'unknown' named tables might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    gid SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    item varchar,
    metadata varchar,
    z_order int,
    foobar int
);
```

and I'm trying to return for each row I update (created by an BEFORE UPDATE trigger):

```
history | action    | table_name | column_name| pkey_id | metadata    |
1       | UPDATE    | test       | item       |       1 |          y  |
_____________________________________________________________________ |
2       | UPDATE    | test       | z_order    |       1 |          y  |
_____________________________________________________________________
3       | UPDATE    | test       | foobar     |       1 |          y  |
```

However, I am having problems calling the specific column_name "metadata" in my query...for id'ing the pkey_id (which might have any column name) I used information_schema:

```
    SELECT
        INTO pkey_column_name
        kcu.column_name
    FROM
        information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
        ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
        JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
        ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
    WHERE
        constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND
        ccu.table_name=tg_relname;

 /// more code ///
  FOR each_entity IN
     EXECUTE 'SELECT text((' || QUOTE_NULLABLE(OLD) || '::"' || QUOTE_IDENT(tg_table_schema) || '"."' || QUOTE_IDENT(tg_relname) || '")."'  || QUOTE_IDENT(pkey_column_name) || '")
                AS pk_val, 
/// more code ///
```

But...my attempts to get the specific column_name "metadata" into my execute query have failed. Ideally I would like to select it by name using attname...but I'm not having much luck...I have a list of each column ('each_column') names (including 'metadata') but no way to call it in the EXECUTE statement...

```
FOR each_column IN
    SELECT
        attname as column_name
    FROM
        pg_attribute
    WHERE
        attrelid =
        (
            SELECT
                oid --  'oid' is the internal Postgresql primary key used for various system tables
            FROM
                pg_class
            WHERE
                relname = tg_relname -- 'tg_relname' is a special Trigger variable that gives the name of the table invoking the trigger
        )
    AND attnum > 0 -- returns no system columns 
LOOP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with (thanks Denis for the advice)~

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/64e41/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
FOR column_name IN SELECT ...
```

Use:

```
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT ...) INTO variable
```

Then use `array_to_string()` with adequate `quote_ident()` calls, or if you need it conditionally or with where clauses, the same with something like:

```
array_to_string((select array(... from unnest(variable) cols where ...)), ',')
```

This should allow you to build any number of select or where clauses (using `' AND '` instead of `','`) as needed, with any number of potential conditions on them.

Comment: cool. But -- say it wasn't an array (I know, ex is not great fixing now), is there a way in dynamic sql to select a specific column from an unspecified table. For ex: select *
from information_schema.COLUMNS
where column_name like '%name%' and table_name like '%emp%'

Comment: You can always build and store your sql query as a text variable, and then execute it... A bit the way you're doing in your 'FOR each_entity IN' block: instead of executing the query directly, you could build an `_sql text` variable, and conditionally concatenate fields and criterias and joins and what not. The only thing to be wary of is escaping, to avoid sql injections.